# Set Focus to Internet Explorer Object in Visual Basic

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, setfocus

Does anybody know how to set focus onto an IE object with Visual Basic?  I've tried `myieobject.SetFocus`, but the compiler errors with this statement.

Comment: How are you binding with IE? Can you show us some code? Also what is the intention behind focusing IE? Are you trying to update any fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed a spreadsheet of mine to "set focus" to Internet Explorer after performing a function so I didn't have to bother clicking on it.  This is what I found to work:

```
      Const myPageTitle As String = "Title of my webpage"
      Const myPageURL As String = "http://www.mywebpage.com"
      Dim myIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
      Dim myIE As InternetExplorer
      Set myIE = GetOpenIEByTitle(myPageTitle, False)


      myIE.visible = false
      DoEvents
      myIE.visible = true  
     'for some reason, making the page invisible then visible always ensures it pops up

    Function GetOpenIEByTitle(i_Title As String, _
                          Optional ByVal i_ExactMatch As Boolean = True) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

  If i_ExactMatch = False Then i_Title = "*" & i_Title & "*"
  'ignore errors when accessing the document property
  On Error Resume Next
  'loop over all Shell-Windows
  For Each GetOpenIEByTitle In objShellWindows
    'if the document is of type HTMLDocument, it is an IE window
    If TypeName(GetOpenIEByTitle.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
      'check the title
      If GetOpenIEByTitle.document.Title Like i_Title Then
        'leave, we found the right window
        Exit Function
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
'First, hide the object even if it's visible
myieobject.Visible = False
' Second, show the object to focusing
myieobject.Visible = True
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Good answer... a little bit of explanation will be cool.

Comment: Great! Ir somply hides the window, and shows it again. During the "show" of the window, it automatically gets focused!

Comment: This is by far the best!!

Answer (score 1):

set `.Visible=True` - if you've lost the screen somewhere in popups, you would have to loop through window titles to activate a specific title.

```
Dim objShell As Shell
Dim objIndex As InternetExplorer

Set objShell = New Shell

For Each objIndex In objShell.Windows
    If TypeName(objIndex.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        If InStr(objIndex.Document.Title, "Stack Overflow") > 0 Then
            objIndex.Visible = True
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next objIndex
```

Here's what you *can* do with the IE object: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Open Internet explorer by shell command , where you can define focus(this is focused and small windows) and after that catch that shell/explorer window and define it as Internet explorer object. Maybe there is better way than sleep to wait.

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub call_IE()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc As HTMLDocument

Set IE = Open_Focused_explorer()
IE.Navigate "google.com"
Set htmldoc = IE.Document

End Sub

Function Open_Focused_explorer() As InternetExplorer
Dim shellWins As ShellWindows

'if windows are 64bit IE is on diferent location
#If Win64 Then
     Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", vbNormalFocus
#Else
    Shell "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", vbNormalFocus
#End If


 'wait until explorer is full loaded
 Sleep 4000

 On Error Resume Next
    'create collection of all explorers
  Set shellWins = New ShellWindows

    If shellWins.Count > 0 Then
        ' Get last one
        Set Open_Focused_explorer = shellWins.Item(shellWins.Count - 1)
    End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```